# Долгий запуск программ в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Всем привет.
Собственно, проблема указана в заголовке. С самого первого запуска идеи наблюдаю долгий запуск программ, даже тот же ХеллоВорд запускается 2-3 секунды. Очень дико напрягает такое положение дел. Причем запуск из консоли менее пол секунды. Сами понимаете, все запускать из консоли не всегда удобно.

В гугле полного решения проблемы не нашел.

Железо: Core 2 Duo 2,0 GHz, 4 Gb RAM
ОС: Mac OS X Mavericks

Может кто сталкивался с подобным? Прошу помочь в решении.

Comment: @SuperHuman преобразовал в ответ.

Comment: мое решение конечно немного проблематичней, но я решил проблему, поставив SSD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из консоли должно запускаться быстрее, потому что не выполняется пересборка. Пересборку можно отключить зайдя в настройки задачи (Run) и удалив её из списка действий, которые нужно выполнить до запуска.

Comment: @Jofsey, спасибо. Помогло :)

Answer (score 0):

А вы кешь очистили? Попробуйте очистит кеш память вашего компа и освободите от ненужных файлов системного диска. Сделайте этого через тотал коммандера или YouUninstallerPro, CCleaner. А еще в VM options можно делать так :
 -Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m .
И вы должны потом File -> Invalidate cache and restart.